# Differentiable function: where am I wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Consider the function

$$f(x, y) = \frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4}$$ not at the origin, but $0$ at the origin. I already provd the continuity of the function at the origin. I have to show if it's differentiable.

Considering some paths, I keep getting

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4} =0$$

Yet when proving in serious way the differentiability, I get stuck. Here is what I did:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vert \frac{x^4y^3}{(x^8+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \vert & \leq \frac{x^4y^2|y|}{(x^8+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\\\
& \leq \frac{x^4y^2|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}2x^4y^2}
\\\\
& = \frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\\\
& \leq \frac{\sqrt{y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\\\
& \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\\\
& = 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

- From line two to line three I used AM/GM: $x^8 + y^4 \geq 2\sqrt{x^8y^4} = 2x^4y^2$ and I reversed

So, am I wrong or is the function not differentiable at zero?

Comment: (A factor $\frac12$ was dropped in the middle of the calculation, but anyway,) this upper bound proves nothing.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think the OP realises that the upper bound proves nothing, hence the question.

Comment: @AnneBauval David is right.

Comment: @AnneBauval The last sentence is a request for a clarification about what I did in terms of majorisation. I cannot find a proper path for which the limit doesn't exist, so I went with the "usual" proof. But ending with such a bound is a dead end

Comment: Then (i.e. if you know where you are wrong) your title is not only vague but misleading. I suggest: "Is $\frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4}$ differentiable at the origin?"

Answer (score 5):

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ You already proved that
$$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\frac{|y|}r.$$

But when $y\ne0$ we also have
$$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\frac{r^4|y|^3}{r(0+y^4)}=\frac{r^3}{|y|}$$
hence
$$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\sqrt{\frac{|y|}r\frac{r^3}{|y|}}=r.$$
Alternatively (without using your upper bound): if $x,y\ne0,$

- $$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\frac{x^4|y|^3}{r(x^8+0)}=\frac{|y|^3}{rx^4}
  $$
- $$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\frac{x^4|y|^3}{r(0+y^4)}=\frac{x^4}{r|y|}$$
  hence
  $$\frac{|f(x,y)|}r\le\sqrt[4]
  {\frac{|y|^3}{rx^4}
  \left(\frac{x^4}{r|y|}\right)^3}=\frac{x^2}r\le r.$$

Comment: I honestly don’t get this. First: why to come back from the beginning with another majorization? Second: why did you just put $x = 0$? Third: why the final majorizations is the product of the two ones?

Comment: Fourth: why cannot we go further from $|y|/r$?

Comment: 1,2: because it works. 4: because it doesn't work. 3: because if $0\le a\le b$ and $c,$ then $a^2\le bc.$